# General time series plotting

Tags: r

I have a couple general questions about plotting data. To begin, I used rbind to collate all my data - which incorporates time, length of the animal, site, year, and loch.

```
time(days) L    Site    Year    Loch
1         2.3    LM     2017   Leven
2         2.34   LM     2017   Leven
...
729       5.09   LM     2017   Leven
730       5.1    LM     2017   Leven
1         2.33   LM     2020   Leven
2         2.343  LM     2020   Leven
...
729       5.228  LM     2017   Leven
730       5.229  LM     2020   Leven
1         2.33   LM     2030   Leven
```

I used simulated climate change temperatures to force my model for every decade until 2060. As you can see, each site has simulated data for 730 days at each decade. Thus, I have 5 sets of 730-day data sets (2017, 2020, 2030, 2040, 2050, and 2060) for each site. Likewise, I have data from 2 lochs (leven and etive), and 6 sites (3 in each loch) for a total of 5840 observations.

How would I plot the graph in order to graph the models by each site with their corresponding year labels or legend?

right now I have something that looks like this:

`qplot(Time, Length, data=Future_Model_Data, colour=Year)`

What kind of tests would you recommend to show change or difference between time series data? I was looking into the Granger test, maybe.

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). p.s. Nobody is feeling really smart.

Comment: If you're asking for statistics help along with your plot help, you might want rewrite this question and add a question to the [stats version of SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Cross-correlation? ccf() in R.